# JQuery height setting

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-selectors

I was trying to modify a code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $('#accordion > li').hover(
        function () {
            var $this = $(this);
            $this.stop().animate({'height':'400px'},500);            
            $('.description',$this).stop(true,true).fadeIn();
        },
        function () {
            var $this = $(this);
            $this.stop().animate({'height':'39px'},1000);          
            $('.description',$this).stop(true,true).fadeOut(500);
        }
    );
});
</script>
```

so that I can make a vertical accordion which I succeed in doing. But I want to accordion to stop on click(on selection) on a link. Please help

Comment: `I want to accordion to stop on click(on selection) on a link` - Do you want the hover to stop after the user click on the link.. If you you can simply unbind mouseenter and mouseleave events. Ex: `.unbind('mouseenter mouseleave');`

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to unbind `hover` on clicking a link. If so you can unbind `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events. hover is a shortcut for `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events.

Try like below,

```
$('#accordion > li').unbind('mouseenter mouseleave')
```